# getting error FB.login() called before FB.init() at file facebook_js_sdk.js

Tags: javascript, android, django, facebook, cordova

I am trying for the Facebook connect plugin.
But i am getting the following error in android log in eclipse "FB.login() called before FB.init() at file facebook_js_sdk.js"

Details for poroject
Phonegap version:- 2.2.0
android 4.4W

my script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
                    {
                                localStorage['domain'] = "http://122.172.50.185";
                                var domain = localStorage['domain'];        
                    });
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() 
            {
                alert("in eventlistener");
                try 
                {
                    FB.init({
                        appId : "1455397484724725",
                        nativeInterface : CDV.FB,
                        useCachedDialogs : false
                    });

                } 
                catch (e) 
                {
                    alert("you are in error");
                    alert(e);
                }

            }, false);

            $(function()
            {
                $('#fac').click(function () 
                {   

                    alert("you are in fac");
                    FB.login(function(response) 
                    {   

                        if (response.authResponse) 
                        {   
                            var domain = localStorage['domain'];
                                $( function() 
                                {
                                    $( '#loadingdots' ).loadingdots({ dots : 5 });
                                });
                                    var photo = $('#fac');
                                    photo.css('visibility', 'hidden');
                                $.ajax(
                                {
                                    url: domain+'/login/android/',                      
                                    data:response.authResponse,
                                    type:"POST",
                                    success:function(xhr, status, success)
                                    {
                                        window.location = 'file:///android_asset/www/index.html';                   
                                    },
                                    error:function(xhr, status, error)
                                    {
                                        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                                        alert(err.Message);                                 
                                    },                  
                                });                                     
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            alert('not logged in');
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        scope : "email"
                    });

                });
            });
    </script>
```

i dont know what wrong i am doing. 
Config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<cordova>


    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->

    <!-- <access origin="https://example.com" /> allow any secure requests to example.com -->
    <!-- <access origin="https://example.com" subdomains="true" /> such as above, but including subdomains, such as www -->
    <access origin=".*"/>

    <log level="DEBUG"/>
    <preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<plugins>
    <plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
    <plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
    <plugin name="Compass" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
    <plugin name="Media" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
    <plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
    <plugin name="Contacts" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
    <plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
    <plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
    <plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
    <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
    <plugin name="Capture" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
    <plugin name="Battery" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
    <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
    <plugin name="Echo" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo" />
    <plugin name="Globalization" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization"/>
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect" value="org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin" />
    <plugin name="ShareSocial" value="com.facebktest.plugins.ShareSocial.ShareSocial"/>
</plugins>
</cordova>
```

Comment: I don't know phonegap, but do you get the "in eventlistener" alert before the "you are in fac" alert? If not it could mean that somehow the `deviceready` event is not fired...

Comment: Yes i am getting that alert.

Comment: And you don't get the "you are in error" alert, right? Because I heard that `FB.init` can fail silently if `appId` is wrong, but I suppose that's what you're checking with the `try-catch` statement...

Comment: yes i am getting the alert "you are in error"

Comment: Oh, ok then it simply means your `FB.init` fails, so obviously you can't call any FB functions that require init... What does the `alert(e)` return?